# Using weakAnd with an array<string> attribute

Tags: vespa

I have a document that has the following two fields:

```
    field label type string {
        indexing: summary | index | attribute
        index: enable-bm25
        attribute: fast-search
    }

    field titles type array<string> { 
        indexing: index | summary | attribute
        index: enable-bm25
        attribute: fast-search
    }
```

and the ranking profile i'm using:

```
    rank-profile profile {
        first-phase {
            expression: max(textSimilarity(label),elementSimilarity(titles))
        }
    }
```

I want to get a document where either its `label` or one of the values in its `titles` contain the words "Hot" and "Springs".

The top document should be this: (as its label contains exactly the two words - "Hot" and "Springs")

```
{
   "label": "Hot Springs"
   "titles": []
}
```

I'm running a query like so:

```
select * from DOC_NAME where weakAnd (label contains "Hot", label contains "Springs", titles contains "Hot", titles contains "Springs")
```

but this document doesn't even appear in the top 10 results.

If I run the query with `OR` instead of `weakAnd` it works as expected:

```
select * from DOC_NAME where label contains "Hot" OR label contains "Springs" OR titles contains "Hot" OR titles contains "Springs"
```

this will return the document above as the TOP result.

Even if I have the query like this:

```
select * from DOC_NAME where weakAnd (label contains "Hot", label contains "Springs") OR weakAnd( titles contains "Hot", titles contains "Springs")
```

I still get the doc above as the top result.

Why wouldn't weakAnd produce this document as a top result?

Comment: Your question has too many different aspects and is not very specific. 

The weakAnd query operator is meant for text fields where the IDF (inverse document frequency) x times the query term weight is used for the inner-scoring and finally exposed to the ranking framework. See https://docs.vespa.ai/en/using-wand-with-vespa.html

Comment: So are you saying that weakAnd should not be used on fields of type array<string>? I can rephrase my question to: Why does the query using only weakAnd NOT produce (almost) the same results as the query using only OR. As far as I understand they should produce almost the same top k results most of the times and in this example the top result is not even in the top 10.

Comment: No, they won't always produce the same results if there is nothing to differentiate the terms (IDF) or query term weight it won't necessarily produce the same results as an exhaustive OR search. The example is so abstract and odd that it's difficult to suggest alternatives.

Comment: Updated my question to make it more concrete. Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [weakAnd](https://docs.vespa.ai/en/using-wand-with-vespa.html#weakand) documentation

> The reason for increasing the target number is that weakAnd uses a ranking function internally (inner product) and the hits which are evaluated by the weakAnd scorer is also evaluated by the first-phase ranking expression.
> Anything similar to classic vector ranking should correlate well with weakAnd inner product scoring, e.g. nativeFieldMatch or bm25 ranking features.Note that because weakAnd relies on feedback identifying which hits are used for first phase ranking to increase its threshold for what's considered a good hit, the special unranked rank profile (which turns off ranking completely) may cause weakAnd queries to become slower than using a real rank profile.

In your case, this fails because you have a max expression in the first-phase configurable ranking. You probably have better success using a different ranking expression in first phase (e.g nativeRank) and your max in a second-phase expression. Or use OR, which does not attempt to be smart.

This is unrelated, but your field definitions don't make much sense. If you need free-text matching capabilities, consider this instead.

````
field label type string {
        indexing: summary | index 
        index: enable-bm25
}```
````

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Can you point me to some resource where I can read how the weakAnd implementation in Vespa works. Just reading the doc I don't quite understand why having a max in the first-phase expression would cause the document from the example to not show up as a top result.

Comment: I think it's covered in full here? https://docs.vespa.ai/en/using-wand-with-vespa.html#weakand

Comment: If you need more background on the WAND algorithm, I suggest https://www.slideshare.net/AndrewZhang44/wand-topk-retrieval